# Finding orthogonal functions

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

Let an inner product be defined on $\mathcal{C}[-1,1]$ in the following manner:
$$\langle f,g \rangle=\int_{-1}^{1} g(x)f(x) dx$$ It is easy to check that this is an inner product, which is $x \perp x^2$. My problem is that is there a way of finding a function $h$ that is $(h \perp x) \wedge (h \perp x^2)$? Normalizing $h$ is easy since I can divide by its norm as a scalar which carries over under the $\int$. sign.

$\textbf{Question: can I find it without using Gram Schmidt}$? I already have a solution that is $$h(x)=\frac{-15}{8}(x^2-3/5)$$ but since we haven't discussed that process in class there must be a simpler way

$$\int_{-1}^{1} xh(x) dx=\int_{-1}^{1} x^2h(x) dx=0$$

Comment: I think the Gram-Schmidt procedure is the standard way to compute such functions. Another method might be to use SVD or some method to compute eigenvectors.

Comment: We have not discussed that either. It's a problem set we have to turn in so there must be an elementary method which is bugging me.

Answer (score 1):

Orthogonal functions for this inner product are Legendre polynomials: [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials), [[2]](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendrePolynomial.html). You'll find that besides the Gram-Schmidt procedure there are other generating formulas: Bonnet’s recursion formula, Rodrigues formula, summation formulas.